# QObject* context in QObject::connect function

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I'v read the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-5) for QObject::connect (for Qt 5.4), but I have a question about the overload

`QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject * sender, PointerToMemberFunction signal, const QObject * context, Functor functor, Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection)`

What exactly is the `context` parameter? What is its purpose? Can it be used to build connections in local event loops in threads?

Can someone provide examples of how/when to use this overload (when the context is not `this`)?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The context object is used in two scenarios.

### Automatic disconnection

Let's first do a step back and ask ourselves: **when does Qt break a connection?**

With the usual `connect(sender, signal, receiver, slot)` connect, there are three possibilities:

1. When someone explicitely calls `disconnect`;
2. When `sender` is deleted;
3. When `receiver` is deleted.

Especially in cases #2 and #3, it just makes sense for Qt to behave that way (actually, it *must* behave that way, otherwise you'd have resource leaks and/or crashes).

---

Now: **when using the `connect` overload taking a functor, when does Qt break a connection?**

Note that without the `context` parameter, there's only one QObject involved: the sender. Hence the answer is:

1. When someone explicitely calls `disconnect`;
2. When `sender` is deleted.

Of course, there's no receiver object here! So only the sender automatically controls the lifetime of a connection.

Now, the problem is that the functor may capture some extra state that can become invalid, in which case is desirable that the connection gets broken automatically. The typical case is with lambdas:

```
connect(sender, &Sender::signal, 
        [&object1, &object2](Param p) 
        { 
            use(object1, object2, p);
        }
);
```

What happens if `object1` or `object2` get deleted? The connection will still be alive, therefore emitting the signal will still invoke the lambda, which in turn will access destroyed objects. And that's kind of bad...

---

For this reason, when it comes to functors, a `connect` overload taking a **context object** has been introduced. A connection established using that overload will be disconnected automatically also

3. when the `context` object is deleted.

You're probably right when you say that a good number of times you're going to see there the very same "main" object used in the functor, for instance

```
connect(button, 
        &QPushButton::clicked,
        otherWidget, 
        [otherWidget]() 
        { 
            otherWidget->doThis(); otherWidget->doThat(); 
        }
);
```

That's just a pattern in Qt -- when setting up connections for sub-objects, you typically connect them to slots on `this` object, hence `this` is probably the most common context. However, in general, you may also end up with something like

```
// manages the lifetime of the resources; they will never outlive this object
struct ResourceManager : QObject 
{
    Resource res1; // non-QObjects
    OtherResource res2;
};

ResourceManager manager;    
connect(sender, signal, manager, [&manager](){ use(manager.res1, ...); });
// or, directly capture the resources, not the handle
```

So, you're capturing part of the state of `manager`.

---

In the most general case, when no `context` object is available, if there's the chance that the objects captured by the lambda survive the connection, then you must capture them by weak pointers, and try to lock those pointers inside the lambda before trying to access them.

### Running a functor in a specific thread/event loop

Very shortly: **when specifying a context object, the functor will be run into the context's thread**, just like normal connections employing a receiver object. Indeed, note that the `connect` overload that takes a context *also* takes a connection type (while the one without context doesn't take one -- connection is always direct).

Again, this is useful because QObject is not reentrant or thread safe, and you must use a QObject only in the thread it lives in. If your functor accesses an object living in another thread, it must be executed in that thread; specifying that object as the context solves the issue.

Comment: I believe the context object has another role: For specifying the thread which runs the functor

Comment: This should be in the Qt documentation!

Comment: very clear answer!