# On C++ lamdas and QTimer. What does this warning mean, and how to get rid of it?

Tags: c++, qt, lambda, qtimer

This question is marked as a *duplicate* of another question that concerns qt's *connect*-method. But since my code does *not* call connect my question cannot be a duplicate. Maybe the answers to the two questions are related somehow, but the two questions are not similar.

I am programming in  C++ using Qt Creator on a Mac (clang compiler).

As is displayed in the screenshot above,  the following line of code:

```
QTimer::singleShot(100.0, [this](){ this->timeout();});
```

yields the warning:

*Pass a context object as 2nd singleShot parameter [clazy-connect-3arg-lambda]*

What does this warning mean and how to get rid it?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/KDE/clazy/blob/master/docs/checks/README-connect-3arg-lambda.md ?

Comment: The warning is intended to let you think about object lifecycles which is very important in (concurrent) programming.

Consider the situation where the "this" pointer is no longer valid after 100ms.
The Qt timer will callback to an object that no longer exists. 
This looks like a false positive (I assume the this object lives for a long time) so you have to check the Qt manual on how to supress this warning

Comment: @paxdiablo, I do not know how to interpret the github comment. Is the warning a "false positive" ? Or should I instead use an overload to singleShot that takes a "context object" ?  I am not sure what is meant by that.

Answer (score 2):

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27954502/8675797) explain about the concept of context in Qt.
In your case i believe passing `this` as context will solve your problem.

Comment: If "context" should be an object that derives from  QObject then "this" will nor work.  But since my object will remain during the lifetime of the application I guess I can ignore the warning (?).

Comment: @ragnarius If `this` doesn't point to a `QObject` instance then I don't think you have any choice other than to treat the warning as a false positive since, if the object *is* deleted before the signal is emitted, `Qt` has no way of knowing about it.